# Backbone.js - Coordinating Layout (instantiation), State and History

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, state

*I am looking for a simple and extensible way of serializing the full state of my Backbone.js application.*

Let's say I want to store the full state (some widget models + meta information such as the layout of the app etc.) in my "GlobalStateModel":

```
var GlobalStateModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        layout : undefined,
        widgetType1Collection : undefined, //Widget models
    },
});
```

I want to do this because then I can easily set corresponding history entries:

```
var HistoryController = Backbone.View.extend({
    model : globalStateModel,

    initialize: function () {   
        _.bindAll(this, "render", "updateHistory");
        this.model.bind("change", this.updateHistory);  
    },

    updateHistory : function () {
        var globalStateModel = this.model.toJSON()
        var state = jQuery.param.querystring("", state )
        appRouter.navigate('v1' + state, false);
    }
});
```

But here comes the tricky part ... I want to have a LayoutController or similar that instantiates widget modules that works together with the above:

```
var LayoutController = Backbone.View.extend({   
    initialize: function () {   
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.model.bind("change:layout", this.render);      
    },

    render : function () {
        var layout = this.model.get("layout");

        switch(layout){
            case "layout-1":
            this.renderLayout1();
            break;

            case "layout-2":
            this.renderLayout2();
            break;
        }
    },

    renderLayout1 : function () {       

        var widgetModel1 = new WidgetModel()
        var widgetController1 = new WidgetController({model : widgetModel1})

        this.model.widgetType1Collection.add(widgetModel1);

        //fetch the right widget model attributes from the global state?
        widgetAttrs = { ..... }
        widgetModel1.set(widgetAttrs)

     },

});
```

Maybe this approach is completely flawed or maybe I'm just missing some plumbing to get this working?

How would you make the LayoutController instantiate 1 or several widgets and have their models be part of the globalState?

So that 1) when their models/collection changes, the globalState is serialized properly and 2) that globalState changes/hashchanges are reflected properly in the widgets?